# VMware Workstation - Set up networking etc

Tags: debian, vmware-workstation

I've created a Debian VM in Vmware workstation 6.5 - Called, "Debian"

I'm planning to install Subversion, trac etc... on here.

How can I set up the VM to be accessed from my Windows 7 host machine?
For example, if I'm running the VM - how can i use my browser on the host machine to navigate to http://debian to access the VM...?

I'm sure I've not set up networking properly...

Comment: How is the vmware networking configured for the debian client? Bridged? NAT? Can the two machines ping each other by address? These would be helpful things to know.

Comment: im not sure - im a vmware novice, where can i check this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would probably be to set up your hosts file (`C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`) to point to the VM's internal IP address.

example:

```
192.168.1.100      debian
```

you can find your vm's IP address using `ifconfig` on debian, or looking at the VMWare adapters in Windows 7's `ipconfig` output.

Answer (score 0):

Please see if this might help. 
http://www.howtoforge.com/debian_sarge_vmware_server_howto

goodluck..

Comment: I think you meant the other way around - unless he's running xrdp on the linux guest :)

Comment: yes, i meant the other way round